# Pandas - How to replace string with zero values in a DataFrame series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing some csv data into a Pandas DataFrame (in Python). One series is meant to be all numerical values. However, it also contains some spurious "$-" elements represented as strings. These have been left over from previous formatting. If I just import the series, Pandas reports it as a series of 'object'.

What's the best way to replace these "$-" strings with zeros? Or more generally, how can I replace all the strings in a series (which is predominantly numerical), with a numerical value, and convert the series to a floating point type?

- Steve

Comment: I've re-posted as more general question about handling accounting format data. See here [Convert a Pandas Series in Accounting Format to a Numeric Series?](http://goo.gl/ol1Fnl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Series.str.replace` and `Series.astype`

```
df = pd.Series(['2$-32$-4','123$-12','00123','44'])
df.str.replace(r'\$-','0').astype(float)

0    203204
1    123012
2       123
3        44
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks - this almost works but trips up on `"($24)"` values.

Comment: If you want to leave only numbers you can use `df.str.replace(r'[^0-9]+','')`

Comment: Thanks - but how do you parse the parentheses to a negative number i.e. `"$(24)"` to `-24`?

Comment: Do you mean there can be a separate minuses? Can you post an example of your data?

Comment: Hi @hellpanderrr I posted a more general question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456364/convert-a-pandas-series-in-accounting-format-to-a-numeric-series which has a solution - thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects) method of the `DataFrame`, with `convert_numeric=True` to change the strings to `NaNs`

From the docs:

> **convert_numeric**:
>   If True, attempt to coerce to numbers (including strings), with unconvertible values becoming NaN.

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
    a   b  c
0  1.  2.  4
1  sd  2.  4
2  1.  fg  5

In [18]: df2 = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [19]: df2
Out[19]: 
    a   b  c
0   1   2  4
1 NaN   2  4
2   1 NaN  5
```

Finally, if you want to convert those `NaNs` to `0`'s, you can use `df.replace`

```
In [20]: df2.replace('NaN',0)
Out[20]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  4
1  0  2  4
2  1  0  5
```

Comment: Note that `pd.to_numeric` is the new hotness; `convert_objects` has been deprecated.

Comment: ah, thanks. I hadn't upgraded to `0.17`, so that option wasn't in my `pandas`. I'll update my answer...

Comment: @DSM it appears that only works on 1D objects though, so converting a `DataFrame` is more involved... or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks - but it looks like my data is a little more polluted. It works for one series but not the other. The series which trips it up contains `"$-"` and `"($24)"` values. After the `pd.to_numeric` it still shows as an object type

Answer (score 4):

Use `.to_numeric` to covert the strings to numeric (set strings to `NaN` using the errors option 'coerce'):

```
df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')
```

and then convert the `NaN` value to zeros using replace:

```
df.replace('NaN',0)
```