# Error while summing a column on dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I am reading multiple files, merging them and calculating sum on a column, below is my code -

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(["file11.csv","file12.csv"], header=0)

df2 = dd.read_csv(["file21.csv","file22.csv"], header=0)

df3 = dd.merge(df1,df2, on = ['ID'] )

df3['COLUMN_1'].sum().compute()
```

The last statement gives below error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-13e0108c3955> in <module>
----> 1 df3['COLUMN_1'].sum().compute()
....
....
....
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'N'
```

Is it because of  character 'N' in the column ? If that is the case how to replace all N with zero ?

Comment: please show some example data

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the `.str` attribute to replace all occurrences of `N` by the string `0` and then convert it into an `int`. Then, you should be able to compute the sum of the `COLUMN_1` column.

Imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

Generate dummy data in `["file11.csv","file12.csv"]`<sup>1</sup>

```
for file_num in range(1, 2+1):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,7)), columns=list("ABCDEFG"))
    df["ID"] = range(1,10+1)
    df.to_csv(f"file1{file_num}.csv", index=False)
```

Generate dummy data in `["file21.csv","file22.csv"]`<sup>1</sup>

```
for file_num in range(1, 2+1):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,7)), columns=list("HIJKLMN"))
    df["ID"] = range(1,10+1)
    df["COLUMN_1"] = list(range(1, 5+1)) + ["N"] * 5
    df.to_csv(f"file2{file_num}.csv", index=False)
```

Load data files

```
df1 = dd.read_csv(["file11.csv","file12.csv"], header=0)
df2 = dd.read_csv(["file21.csv","file22.csv"], header=0)

>>> print(df1)
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   A      B      C      D      E      F      G     ID
npartitions=2                                                        
               int64  int64  int64  int64  int64  int64  int64  int64
                 ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
                 ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
Dask Name: read-csv, 2 tasks

>>> print(df2)
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   H      I      J      K      L      M      N     ID COLUMN_1
npartitions=2                                                                 
               int64  int64  int64  int64  int64  int64  int64  int64   object
                 ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...      ...
                 ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...      ...
Dask Name: read-csv, 2 tasks
```

Merge

```
df3 = dd.merge(df1,df2, on = ['ID'] )
```

**Replace `N` by string "0" and then convert to integer `dtype`** (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440402/4057186))

```
df3["COLUMN_1"] = df3["COLUMN_1"].str.replace('N','0').astype(int)
```

Compute sum

```py
>>> print(df3['COLUMN_1'].sum().compute())
60
```

1 guessing at the format of your data. Hopefully the dummy data that is generated here fits your format. If not, please post some data in the question, as suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129027/error-while-summing-a-column-on-dask-dataframe/65152725#comment115146925_65129027).