# Add one to each row in a Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I have an excel sheet I am trying to manipulate python and I want to add 1 to each row in one specific column. The only problem is, is that the column is an object, so I think that is hindering me from adding to it. Here is what I came up with:

```
FV_Absence = FV_Absence["Previous Letter Count"] + 1
```

When I run this I get the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str".

The data looks something like this:

```
Student Number     Previous Letter Count
3243                -
3423                -
2311                1.0
```

Also, I need to consider the fact that there are some null values, and I am trying to remove the trailing zeros. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are those dashes zero and need a 1 added to get 1 or are those dashes missing data and should be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a dataframe to test, but you can convert the datatype of the column to integers like this:
First:

```
FV_Absence.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)
```

Then:

```
# Convert single column to int dtype.
FV_Absence['Previous Letter Count'] = FV_Absence['Previous Letter Count'].astype('int')
```

After this you can add 1 to the column like it is an integer.

Comment: So, when I run the first code you posted I get the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'. I guess I don't have null values, but the '-' is giving me trouble.

Comment: Yeah so you are gonna have to turn those values into a number first.
Try this and lmk if it works:
You need numpy imported as np.
`df.replace('-', np.nan, inplace=True)`
And then after you do this then run the second code I sent

Comment: @AndrewSmith
Also I think that this might cause trouble when adding 1 since the values will be 0 and now 1, so consider this when trying to fix. Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440234/pandas-how-to-replace-string-with-zero-values-in-a-dataframe-series

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to convert the series to numeric, coercing the non-numeric values to `NaN`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# for repeatability
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({"col0": np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,))})

# make 2 random values a hyphen ("-")
df.loc[df.col0.sample(2).index, "col0"] = "-"

print(df)
```

```
  col0
0    -
1    0
2    -
3    3
4    7
```

```py
# has dtype "object"
df.col0.dtype
```

```
dtype('O')
```

```py
# convert to numeric, coercing non-numeric values to NaN
df["col0"] = pd.to_numeric(df.col0, errors="coerce")
```

```py
# hyphens were converted to NaN
print(df.col0)
```

```
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    7.0
Name: col0, dtype: float64
```

```py
# add 1 to the columns
print(df.col0.add(1))
```

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    4.0
4    8.0
Name: col0, dtype: float64
```